# Froala Editor how save content to textarea before send form

Tags: jquery, html, wysiwyg, froala

I use in the project Froala. The textarea element is in the form to be sent to the server. I add any text to Froala and click the submit form button. But the textarea field on the server is empty(NULL). 
I think I need to call the Froala method to prepare the textarea before submitting the form to the server, but I do not know which one.

What could be the problem?

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdatePost", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "postForm" }))
{
    <textarea id="PreviewText" name="PreviewText"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-success w-100">Save</button>
}
```

**Server**

```
[HttpPost]
public JObject UpdatePost([FromForm] Post postForm)
{
    //...
}
```

**Javascript**

```
       $('#PreviewText').froalaEditor({
            language: 'ru',
            imageUploadURL: '../UploadImage',
            imageUploadParams: {
                postId: Tmigin.CMS.PostEditor.postId
            },
            imageManagerLoadURL: '../LoadImages',
            imageManagerLoadParams: {
                postId: Tmigin.CMS.PostEditor.postId
            },
            imageManagerDeleteURL: '../DeleteImage',
            imageManagerDeleteParams: {
                postId: Tmigin.CMS.PostEditor.postId
            }
        });
```

**Update**
Similar problems in the compatibility of jQuery Form Plugin and Froala.

**Fixed**

https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/2233

Answer (score 1):

As per your note on this issue on the Froala github issues page,

> If before sending to the form server, you call this:

```
$('#PreviewText').froalaEditor('events.trigger', 'blur');
```

> then you can get values from the editor.

Copied here to assist others who may not find your note on github.